# Overrule box-shadow

Tags: html, css, box-shadow

I have a rule where all images in a  get a box-shadow. Now there is one particular image that shouldn't have a box-shadow, but is in the  area. Now, if I give that image an ID or class, this will be given higher priority, which is good. But how do I undo the box-shadow? Setting it to 0px doesn't work.

Thanks!
John

Comment: have you tried box-shadow: none; to ovverride the previous rule?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `none` for the box shadow value.  According to [the Mozilla docs](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/css/box-shadow), `none` is the initial value.

Answer (score 3):

From http://www.welovecss.com/showthread.php?t=5863

```
a > img {
box-shadow: none;
-moz-box-shadow: none;
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To remove the box-shadow:

```
#elementSelector {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 transparent;
    /* or:
    box-shadow: none;
    */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`.imagesselector #specificimage { box-shadow: none; -moz-box-shadow: none; -webkit-box-shadow: none; }`

Answer (score 0):

The keyword `none` is very much like `false` in a programming language, and will nullify almost every CSS attribute.

So:

```
box-shadow: none;
```